# Changing the way figure reference appears in LaTeX

Tags: cross-referencing

How can one make LaTeX insert `Figure` into `\ref` calls automatically, i.e. instead of writing:

`See data in Figure ~\ref{fig:JobInformationDialog}`

simply write:

`See data in \ref{fig:jobInformationDialog}`

and have LaTeX insert `Figure [fignum]` when it gets compiled?

Answer (score 9):

A very easy way is provided by the `prettyref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{prettyref}
\newrefformat{fig}{Figure~[\ref{#1}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \rule{10cm}{2cm}
  \captionof{figure}{This is my caption}
  \label{fig:first}
\end{center}

Please see \prettyref{fig:first}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides `\autoref` which automatically sets a title with every reference. For `figure`s, this is `Figure`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\rule{10cm}{2cm}
  \caption{This is my caption}
  \label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

Please see \autoref{fig:first}.
\end{document}
```

The starred version `\autoref*` removes the internal document hyperlinking for that specific link only.

Answer (score 2):

The [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package provides macros `\cref` and `\Cref` that do exactly this, in a very configurable way (see documentation):

[image: A captioned figure with a reference using cleveref]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\rule{10cm}{2cm}
  \caption{This is my caption}
  \label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

Please see \cref{fig:first}.
\end{document}
```

Using `hyperref` is optional, but it should be loaded before `cleveref`.